# How can these two queries be combined?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the poor question title, I'm not sure of the correct terminology to describe what I'm asking.

I have two tables:

posts:

```
p_id | p_author | p_text
```

post_comments:

```
pc_id | pc_p_id | pc_author | pc_text
```

The pc_p_id for each comment corresponds to the p_id of the post.

I want to select:

1. The p_id and p_text for all of the posts from a specific author
2. The number of comments for the corresponding post

I can do the first part with a query like this (supposing "1" is an author):

```
SELECT p_id, p_text FROM posts WHERE p_author = 1
```

And I can get the number of comments for a specific post like this (supposing "12" is a post id):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_comments WHERE pc_p_id = 12
```

My question is, how can I combine the two queries so that I get the p_id and p_text for all of the posts from a specific author, along with the number of comments for the corresponding posts?

I tried using a LEFT JOIN like the following, but it gives me a syntax error:

```
SELECT t1.p_id, t1.p_text, t2.COUNT(*)
FROM posts t1 LEFT JOIN post_comments t2
WHERE t1.p_author = 1 AND t2.pc_p_id = t1.p_id 
ORDER BY t1.p_id DESC
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b975

Comment: Can you put up a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: How are the two tables related? Are p_author and pc_author equivalent?

Comment: @Melanie - I updated my question. The pc_p_id for each comment corresponds to the p_id of the post. No, the p_author and pc_author are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p_id, p_text, count(1)
FROM posts p
   JOIN post_comments pc
   ON p.p_id = pc.pc_p_id
WHERE p_author = 1
GROUP BY p_id, p_text
```

Here is the edited version that does an embedded select:

```
SELECT p_id, p_text,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM post_comments WHERE pc_p_id = p.p_id) AS count
FROM posts p
WHERE p_author = 1
```

I verified this in your fiddle

Comment: Thanks, this sort of works, but it doesn't return posts with no comments. SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b975

Comment: simply change to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b975/17. It almost works, but it returns "1" for the second post when the number of comments is actually "0". So something is not working correctly.

Comment: ah, well, with LEFT OUTER, you will get empty rows that don't match any rows in the comments table. This is how it should work. So, if you want ALL the post rows and a count of the post comments, you will need to do an embedded select for that. I will try and edit this post to show that.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT_JOIN is used when you want all rows from the left-hand table, but there may not be corresponding rows in the right-hand table. Otherwise you want a straight (inner) join. Also, when using an aggregation function like COUNT() you have to use a GROUP_BY clause if you have any non-aggregate columns selected.

Comment: There may not be rows in the right-hand table, though. This is like a blog, where an author can publish a post, then other people can post comments. A post may or may not have corresponding comments.

Comment: Then the left join is appropriate, but will still require a group by clause.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT p.p_id, p.p_text, count( pc.pc_id )  AS Count
FROM posts p, post_comments pc
WHERE pc.pc_p_id = p.p_id
AND p.p_author =1
AND pc.pc_p_id =12